# check internet connection is Connected or not in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin,

I would like to know if there is another way to check internet connection.

I Have used`CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected` from the plugin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity but it is not worked when I put my wifi off

I have also used [Xamarin.Essentails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) but still not working..

```
private bool CheckInternet()
        {
            var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

            if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  Are you testing on a real device or emulator?  Are you testing on a device that has both WiFi and cell capability, or just WiFi?  Have you tried using the event handlers that detect changes in the network?

Comment: it is emulator and on microsoft website it says you can have internet acces but if there is not connextion it will keep working like there is internet

Comment: Limitations
It is important to note that it is possible that Internet is reported by NetworkAccess but full access to the web is not available. Due to how connectivity works on each platform it can only guarantee that a connection is available. For instance the device may be connected to a Wi-Fi network, but the router is disconnected from the internet. In this instance Internet may be reported, but an active connection is not available.

Comment: yes, that is why the plugin also gives you ping tools: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html

Comment: Do you need to capture when connectivity changes? For example when the connection disconnects or connects back again?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout full documentation [link](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/)

You can use

```
public async Task<string> MakeWebRequest()
{
    if(!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
      //You are offline, notify the user
      return null;
    }

    //Make web request here
}
```